# Snap.SVG s.node.offsetLeft [Top] is undefined?

Tags: snap.svg

In Snap.SVG I need the position of a SVG container left upper corner. I get the needed coordinates with

```
s.mousemove(moveFunc)
```

but they are relative to the position of the html body. The html document is responsive. The result useing

`s.node.offsetLeft`

or

```
s.node.offsetTop
```

is undefined. A SVG container with an ID and the use of

```
document.getElementByID('usedId').offsetLeft
```

or other offset... give also 'undefined'. The results are independent of the browser. So far I couldn't find a usefull answer or example. I hope to get some help.

For completion to IAN's answer. The html body ist centered to the viewport of the browser and the contents are responsible. The SVG container should be centered in the body. The mousemove event gives me the correct coordinates relative to the viewport. If I want for example that a SVG grafic element will follow the mouse or be placed at the mousepointer I need the relative coordinates of the SVG container's upper left corner and not the absolut coordinates with x=0 and y=0. How can I get these coordinates? For a absolut positioned html element I can get the needed offsets but not for the SVG.

sorry, I tried a jsfiddle but unsuccessful. Here the the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<title>Test.svg</title>
<style>
body {max-width:62em;margin:0 auto;overflow-y:scroll;}
main {background: #ddd;}
svg {background:#eee;border:1px dotted #3983ab;width:100%;height:auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<h1>Test responsiv SVG</h1>
<div style="text-align: center">
<svg id="svgout" style="max-width:500px" viewBox="0 0 500 250" ></svg>
</div>
<script>
var s = Snap('#svgout');
var c1 = s.circle(0,0,10).attr({fill: '#00f'});
function mausPosi(event, x, y ) {
c1.attr({cx: x, cy: y});
mC.attr({'text': x+'/'+y});
oL.attr({'text': s.node.offsetLeft});
};
s.mousemove(mausPosi);
var oL = s.text(10,100, 'Offset...: ');
var mC = s.text(10,150, 'mouseCoord:');
</script>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

For the circle following the mousecurser in the correct way I have to substract the coordinates of the upper left corner of SVG. The mouse event return the coordinates inside the SVG relativ to the body (main). For the element (circle) the coordinates of the upper point ist (0/0).

Ian, I found jsfiddle.net/xJ4Lj/36/ (yours?) with s.node.offset... only working good if the SVG container remains left of the browsers viewport. The returned value in an additional text gives undefined.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do ? It's unusual to need to bother with things like offsets even with a responsive setup and Snap handlers.

Comment: Hello Ian, I have edited my question to clarify

Comment: Something seem astray the x,y should be relative to the svg container, possible to pop up a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Hello Ian, sorry no jsfiddle but the used html / script code

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood earlier, I've added a possible answer which may help.

Answer (score 0):

When there are differences from the screen coordinates to the svg element, we need to do a transformation on the points, to the svg coordinates space. We can find that out from the matrix given by element.getScreenCTM().

It's a little bit complex, so I typically use a plugin I made, just include that at the top before you create a Snap paper instance. Basically create an svg point, find the inverse matrix of the transformation from the screen to the svg paper, and then do a transformation on the points using that.

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {

    Element.prototype.getCursorPoint = function( x, y ) {
            var pt = this.paper.node.createSVGPoint();      
            pt.x = x; pt.y = y;
            return pt.matrixTransform( this.paper.node.getScreenCTM().inverse()); 
    }

});

...

function mausPosi(event, x, y ) {
    var cpt = s.getCursorPoint(x,y)
    c1.attr({cx: cpt.x, cy: cpt.y});
};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aoLnLyx7/2/)

Comment: Your answer is very instructive for me and I have to spend some time for detailed understanding. The result works fine. Snap.SVG is more complicated than Flash with ActionScript 2 (3). Thankyou for time and your patience.